# My CSS Doesn't Impact My Div Element In Electron JS

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, electron, desktop-application

I am a beginner in Electron JS, and I want to create a basic messaging app. I created a login page that directs you to main page; however I have encountered a problem on main page. I put the logo in the top left and I want to change my top navigation bar color slightly to make it clear. Here is my HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<title>Chelly</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
<script src="preload.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="main-page">
    <div id="main-page-top" class="top-main">
        <img src="Logo.jpeg" id="main-logo"> 
    </div>
    
    <div>
        
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I have tried to select the element and change background color. Something like:

```
#main-page-top {
    background-color: rgb(118, 117, 117);
}
```